# Installation of r packages failed with the same error "GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found"

Tags: r, debian, guix

When I tried to install r package "osmdata" (or any other package) with command

```
install.packages("osmdata")
```

it failed with error

```
"GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home...R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-osmdata/00new/osmdata/libs/osmdata.so)
```

host system is debian, r is installed using package manager Guix.

Answer (score 1):

The error means: `osmdata.so` was compiled with `g++` version 11.1.0 (ABI mapping of `GLIBCXX` to `g++` version is documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)), but the version of `libstdc++.so.6` installed on the system is older, and doesn't provide `GLIBCXX_3.4.29`.

You need to get a version of `osmdata.so` *appropriate* for your system, or you need to build it from source, or you need to update your `libstdc++.so.6`.

P.S. Your question has *nothing* to do with `glibc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing package `r-guix-install` from Guix package manager and using this command

```
guix.install::guix.install("osmdata")
```